# Galois Theory/Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm having trouble with this exercise, I do not understand how to imagine K. To do a know I need to show $\alpha$ is algebraic but I can't think of the minimal polynomial $\alpha$ for which $\alpha$ is a root.

Let $K := \mathbb{F_5[x]}/(x^4 + x^2 + x + 1).$

(a) Let $α = x + (x^4 + x^2 + x + 1)$ ∈ K. Write down a basis for $K/\mathbb{F_5}$ in terms
of α.

(b) Express $α^6$
in terms of your basis.

(c) How many elements does K have?

(d) Let φ : K → K be given by φ(β) = $β^5$
. Show that φ is an automorphism
of K.

Comment: $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$ by design...

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but is particulary useful in theory of field extensions. Let's say that you have a field $k$ and its ring of polynomials $k[X]$. Now, given $f\in k[X]$, is there a field $K$ that contains a root of $f$? This is extremely important step in finding algebraic closure of a field. The answer to the question is positive! We can safely assume that $f$ is irreducible (if not, take one of its irreducible factors). Then $(f)$ is maximal ideal in $k[X]$ and $k[X]/(f)$ is thus a field. Let $\alpha = x + (f)$. Then $\alpha$ is root of $f$. (tbc)

Comment: This is because $f(\alpha) = \operatorname{ev}_{\alpha}f$ and evaluation at $\alpha$ is precisely canonical epimorphism $x\mapsto x+(f)$. Since $f$ is in kernel of that epi, it follows that $f(\alpha) = 0$. In your particular case $x + (x^4 + x^2 + x + 1)$ is a root of $x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

a) Using euclidean division by $x^4+x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$, $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3\}$ is a basis of $K/\mathbb{F}_5$.

b) $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4+x^2+x+1$.

c) $K$ is of dimension $4$ on $\mathbb{F}_5$, hence there is $5^4$ elements in $K$.

d) $K$ is of characteristic $5$.

Comment: I don't really understand why $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4+x^2+x+1$

Comment: @Soul-Surviver123, please see my comments above.

Comment: Technically for d you also need to verify that $x^4+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$ so that the Frobenius map is actually an automorphism.

Comment: You are indeed very right!